How to Dynamically Paginate a Table in R PDF
I am generating a PDF in R that displays a table with pagination. The first page should include a header with 22 rows below it, and each following page should display 40 rows. Since the function doesn’t automatically detect the end of a page, I’ve explicitly set the number of rows per page: 22 for the first page (accounting for introductory text) and 40 for all remaining pages.
That is the structure of my data:
structure(list(stratum = c("term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA1", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab1|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds1|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex1|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c832|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term1|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", "term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0", 
"term2|c884|sex2|pds2|diab0|HTA0"), rando_bras = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -384L), class = "data.frame"). 

It should be passed to this function and printed as a PDF. However, I haven't succeeded in formatting the table on the page as I want.
Here is the function I created:
RandCapBalance <- function(randomization_object, output_path = "Randomization_Balance.pdf") {
  # Extraction du jeu de données complet et calcul du nombre de strates
  full_dataset <- randomization_object$tables$full_dataset
  num_strata <- length(unique(full_dataset$stratum))
  
  # Gestion du cas où aucune strate n'est définie
  if (num_strata == 0) {
    full_dataset <- full_dataset %>% mutate(stratum = "No stratum")
  }
  
  # Création de la table d'équilibre avec dplyr et tidyr
  balance_df <- full_dataset %>%
    count(stratum, rando_bras) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = rando_bras, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
    mutate(Total = rowSums(select(., -stratum)))
  
  # Informations de configuration de randomisation
  strat_vars <- randomization_object$settings$strat_vars
  strat_vars_text <- if (is.null(strat_vars) || length(strat_vars) == 0) {
    "There is no stratification variable."
  } else {
    paste(strat_vars, collapse = ", ")
  }
  
  ratios <- if (is.null(randomization_object$settings$ratio)) {
    "Equal size ratio"
  } else {
    paste(randomization_object$settings$ratio, collapse = ", ")
  }
  
  treatment_arms <- paste(randomization_object$settings$treatment_arms, collapse = ", ")
  
  # Démarrer la sortie PDF
  pdf(output_path, width = 8.5, height = 11)
  
  # Première page : afficher les informations de randomisation
  grid.newpage()
  y_pos <- 0.9
  grid.text("Randomization Balance Summary", x = 0.5, y = y_pos, just = "center", 
            gp = gpar(fontsize = 18, fontface = "bold", col = "#2E86C1"))
  y_pos <- y_pos - 0.05
  
  # Afficher les informations de stratification et de bras de traitement
  grid.text(paste("Number of Strata:", num_strata), x = 0.1, y = y_pos, just = "left", 
            gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface = "bold", col = "#2874A6"))
  y_pos <- y_pos - 0.03
  grid.text(paste("Stratification Variables:", strat_vars_text), x = 0.1, y = y_pos, just = "left", 
            gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, col = "#34495E"))
  y_pos <- y_pos - 0.03
  grid.text(paste("Treatment Arms:", treatment_arms), x = 0.1, y = y_pos, just = "left", 
            gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, col = "#34495E"))
  y_pos <- y_pos - 0.03
  grid.text(paste("Ratios:", ratios), x = 0.1, y = y_pos, just = "left", 
            gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, col = "#34495E"))
  
  # Variables de pagination
  rows_per_page <- 22  # Nombre de lignes pour la première page
  start_row <- 1
  num_rows <- nrow(balance_df)
  first_page <- TRUE
  
  # Boucle pour afficher les lignes de la table avec pagination
  while (start_row <= num_rows) {
    # Calculer l'index de fin pour la page en cours
    end_row <- min(start_row + rows_per_page - 1, num_rows)
    
    # Sous-ensemble des données pour la page en cours
    table_page <- balance_df[start_row:end_row, ]
    page_rows <- nrow(table_page)
    
    # Définir les couleurs pour la page actuelle
    page_fill_colors <- c(
      rep("#D1E8FF", page_rows),                        # Couleur de la colonne des strates
      rep("#EBF5FB", page_rows * (ncol(balance_df) - 2)), # Couleur des colonnes de traitement
      rep("#D1E8FF", page_rows)                         # Couleur de la colonne Total
    )
    
    # Appliquer le thème avec des couleurs dynamiques pour la page actuelle
    table_theme <- ttheme_minimal(
      core = list(
        fg_params = list(col = "black"),
        bg_params = list(fill = page_fill_colors, col = NA)
      ),
      colhead = list(
        fg_params = list(col = "white", fontface = "bold"),
        bg_params = list(fill = "#2E86C1")  # Couleur de l'en-tête
      )
    )
    
    # Créer la table grob pour la page actuelle
    table_grob <- tableGrob(table_page, rows = NULL, theme = table_theme)
    
    # Affichage de la page
    if (!first_page) {
      grid.newpage()
      y_pos <- 1  # Commencer en haut des pages suivantes
    } else {
      y_pos <- y_pos - 0.1  # Position pour la première page
      first_page <- FALSE
    }
    
    # Dessiner la table dans le viewport
    pushViewport(viewport(y = y_pos, height = unit(0.7, "npc"), just = "top"))
    grid.draw(table_grob)
    popViewport()
    
    # Mise à jour pour la page suivante
    start_row <- end_row + 1
    rows_per_page <- 40  # Changer à 40 lignes après la première page
  }
  
  # Fermer le PDF
  dev.off()
  
  message("Randomization balance summary saved to ", output_path)
  return(balance_df)
}

